# Apache SVN, error 500 on arch linux

Tags: linux, apache, svn

I used https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Subversion_Setup guide to install my svn repository, still, I'm not able to get to my repository. Here's the output of svn co:

```
[ots@localhost test]$ svn co https://192.168.0.21/svn/otclient_modules --username kosto
Authentication realm: <https://192.168.0.21:443> SVN Repositories
Password for 'kosto': //no matter if i enter good or wrong
svn: E175002: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'https://192.168.0.21/svn/otclient_modules'
svn: E175002: Server sent unexpected return value (500 Internal Server Error) in response to OPTIONS request for 'https://192.168.0.21/svn/otclient_modules'
```

thanks in advance

Comment: What you have posted is too general. There might be more information in apache error logs.

Comment: 1. Show location part for svn of your Apache 2. show `svn ls https://192.168.0.21/svn/otclient_modules` 3. Test this repo with browser

Comment: browser says 403: forbidden,
output of ls is the same as co
svn part is in virtual hosts of httpd-ssl file and it looks like
"<Location /svn>
   DAV svn
   SVNParentPath /home/svn/repositories
   AuthzSVNAccessFile /home/svn/.svn-policy-file
   AuthName "SVN Repositories"
   AuthType Basic
   AuthUserFile /home/svn/.svn-auth-file
   Satisfy Any
   Require valid-user
</Location>"

Comment: I reposted my question, it's much better described now.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13634443/problems-with-configuration-of-svn-error-code-500

 Please close this if there's a possibility to do so.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in permissions. chgrp www-data on svn config files (policy files), and directory that contains them.